# Iterating fieldA in CSV file, where fieldB has specified value

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, csv

I've been trying to setup a script to run on gitbash, to process a CSV file so each record that has a specific value, the last field is changed from empty (`""`) to a value that iterates from 1 to 16.  Also, the updating value is prepended by some text.

The field should look like `REP0001`, end up as `REP0100`, then start over `REP0001`, for each record in the CSV file that matches.

Here's a sample of the input text:

```
"00:30:00","01:00:00","10/14/2014","RETURN","PASADENA","TX","12:30:00","sedan","","","corporate","CO01353"
"01:00:00","01:30:00","10/14/2014","RENT OUT","HOUSTON","TX","00:30:00","sedan","","","personal",""
```

The first line example, I don't want to change, but still include it in the output.
The second line example, I want to change the last field from `""` to a value that starts with `REP0001` and iterates to `REP0100`, then starts over at `REP0001`.

Here's a sample of the desired text:

```
"01:00:00","01:30:00","10/14/2014","RENT OUT","HOUSTON","TX","00:30:00","sedan","","","personal","REP0001"
```

I did try `sed`, as well as `awk` but I'm not a pro at scripting.  I have only been able to put together the part that finds the records with the value I want, and insert the value I want. But I don't know how to do the iteration magic:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","} $4 ~ /"RENT OUT"/ {$12="\042""REP0001""\042"}1' Rentals.csv  > output
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to do this?  The file itself has about 2000 lines in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","} $4 ~ /"RENT OUT"/ {NF--;printf $0; x=x%100;x++; printf ",\"REP%04i\"\n",x;next} 1' rentals.csv 
"00:30:00","01:00:00","10/14/2014","RETURN","PASADENA","TX","12:30:00","sedan","","","corporate","CO01353"
"01:00:00","01:30:00","10/14/2014","RENT OUT","HOUSTON","TX","00:30:00","sedan","","","personal","REP0001"
```

The only part that is changed is this command:

```
$4 ~ /"RENT OUT"/ {NF--;printf $0; x=x%100;x++; printf ",\"REP%04i\"\n",x;next}
```

Taking each new piece one at a time:

- `NF--`

  This removes the (blank) last field from the line.
- `printf $0

  This prints the line (now without its last field).
- `x=x%100;x++`

  This takes the counter `x` modulo 100 and then increments it by 1.  In this way, the counter will cycle from 1 to 100 and back to 1.
- `printf ",\"REP%04i\"\n",x`

  This prints our new last field that includes the counter.
- `next`

  Since we have already printed this line, we tell `awk` to skip the rest of the commands and start over with the `next` line.

Comment: this works great!  and thanks very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Another (a little bit more compacted) version with `sprintf`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $4 ~ /"RENT OUT"/ {$12=sprintf("\"REP%04i\"",++i);i=i%100}1'
```

Comment: +1. I think this one is less complicated.

Comment: this is less complicated, but works great also! thanks for providing another great answer